# SQL Server : UNION ALL but remove duplicate IDs by choosing first date of occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I am unioning two queries but I'm getting an ID that occurs in each query. I do not know how to keep only the first time the id occurs. Everything else about the row is different. In general, it will be hard to know which of the two queries I will have to keep a duplicate on, therefore, I need a general solution.

I was thinking about creating a temp table and choosing the min date (once the date has been converted to an int).

Any ideas on the proper syntax?

Comment: Don't you have anything better to do than edit my Query?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `row_number()` function.  This will assign a sequential number, starting with 1, to each row with the same id (based on the `partition by` clause).  The ordering of the sequence is determined by the `order by` clause.  So, the following assigns `1` to the earliest date for each `id`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date asc) as seqnum
      from ((select *
             from <subquery1>
            ) union all
            (select *
             from <subquery2>
            )
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The final `where` clause simply filters for the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the keyword UNION, then it will remove duplicates from the two data sets you are working with. UNION ALL preserves duplicates.

You can view the specifics here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Thanks, never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only have one of the 2 records and they are not identical you will have to filter them yourself.  You may need to do something like the following.  THis may be possible to do with the one (select union select) block but this should get you started.

```
select *
from (
select id
     , date
     , otherstuf
from table_1
union all
select  id
     , date
     , otherstuf
from table_2
      ) x1
, (
select id
     , date
     , otherstuf
from table_1
union all
select  id
     , date
     , otherstuf
from table_2
      ) x2
where x1.id = x2.id 
  and x1.date < x2.date
```

Although rethinking this if you go down a path like this why bother to UNION it?